# How to add a line in xmgrace plot

Tags: xmgrace

I have a plot of distance vs. time for a large set of data. I want to draw a line, say, parallel to x-axis at a distance 2.00 (in some scale) i.e. need to add another plot of y =2.
Any help might be useful;I did it by transferring the plot in another program but I want to stick in xmgrace.

Comment: Where is the code you currently have, and where part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: xmgrace file.txt ; The file consists of two column. On the plot, I want to add another plot of y =2.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily by creating a new data set based on the equation *y* = 2.

From the Edit menu:

```
Edit > Data Sets
```

Now in the "Data Set Properties" window:

```
Edit > Create New > By Formula
```

Now you have to define a formula. Since you want a straight line you only need two points that correspond to the equation *y* = 2 and that sit at the extrema of your desired plot range. I suggest the following parameters:

```
"Start at" = 0
"Stop at" = <the final time of your data set>
"Length" = 2
"Set type" = "XY"
X = $t
Y = 2
```